# Is it safe to delete the contents of Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup if using iCloud?

Tags: macos, iphone, backup

My /Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup is 5GB and I'd really like to reclaim that space if I can.

I back up my iPhone, iPad, and iPod Touch to iCloud, so is there any reason not to simply delete the 9000+ legacy backups in this folder?

Comment: If you wanna save space, try the free app monolingual, which removes duplicate binaries of apps written for power pc processors… saves like 2gb

Answer (score 37):

Yes, it is safe to delete it, if you are sure you want to *lose* those backups.

To do so, in a more *elegant* way, just:

1. Open **iTunes Preferences**
2. Click *Devices*
3. Locate the backup for the iOS device you want to delete, select it, and click **Delete Backup**.
4. Confirm you wish to remove the selected backup by clicking Delete Backup.
5. Click OK to close the iTunes Preferences Window.

Extracted from [Apple's support document about iOs backups.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946)

**Confirmed:** Deleting through iTunes will delete **all** the backUp files of the selected device.

Comment: The problem is that there are over 9000 files in that directory, and there are only TWO devices (each with one backup) listed in the iTunes Preferences panel.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but you could try deleting, from the iTunes preferences, the backUp for one of the devices, and see if it deletes all the backUps for it. Or just, *cough* delete the content of the folder.

Comment: Judging by the dates, there are several backups in there for the one device.  Maybe, if you do a "restore from backup" you would get to choose among them?

Comment: I believe the folder also includes downloaded copies of iOS updates, if you have upgraded from itunes

Answer (score 5):

Added macOS Catalina 10.15 update below for delete backup instructions

1. Connect the device
2. On a Mac with macOS Catalina 10.15 or later, open the Finder. On a Mac with macOS Mojave 10.14 or earlier, or on a PC, open iTunes. Click your device.
3. In Finder, under the General tab, click Manage Backups to see a list of your backups. From here, you can right-click on the backup that you want, then select Delete or Archive. In iTunes, choose Preferences, then click Devices. From here, you can right-click on the backup that you want, then choose Delete or Archive. Click OK when you're finished.
4. Click Delete Backup, then confirm.

Official documentation: https://support.apple.com/en-hk/HT204215#deleteiTunes

Comment: Of course this won't work if you no longer have the device. Wasn't a problem in iTunes, but is now. :-(

Comment: I just tried the 'Finder' method on Catalina, and I can see that the 'Manage Backups' dialog lists the backups for all devices, not just the one that's plugged in.  So you could put any device and remove the backups for the device that you don't have any more.

Answer (score 0):

it is absolutely safe if you do not require them.
to delete the backups on mac with osx 13+ you shall need to go to finder.
there find your drive and select manage storage,
finally there you will find your ios backups

[image]

to see your drive you need to enable it in finder sidebar

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: On a professional site, you should use proper English.

Comment: @JRFerguson sorry i came here from stackoverflow